# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined - but it worked fine before?

Tags: javascript, fetch

Suddenly getting "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined", even though the code has been working fine up until now.

This is the fetch function I'm trying to use:

```
document.getElementById("getAllJokes").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
    fetch(url + 'all')
        .then(res => res.json()) 
        .then(data => {
             //console.log("data", data);
             document.getElementById("jokeTable").innerHTML = html+makeTableAllJokes()(data); //Renders joke table
             //console.log(makeTable(data));
        });
});
```

This is the map function:

```
  function makeTableAllJokes(data) {
    createTable = data.map(function (e) {
            return (
                `<tr><td>
                ${e.id} 
                </td><td> 
                ${e.joke}
                </td><td>
                ${e.topic} 
                </td>`
            );
        }).join(" ");
        
    return createTable;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter you pass should be inside the brackets:

change this:

```
makeTableAllJokes()(data)
```

to:

```
makeTableAllJokes(data)
```

Comment: Totally missed that! Thank you. It's a group project so I didn't notice anyone having added that. I just woke up to it not working lol.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```js
document.getElementById("jokeTable").innerHTML = html+makeTableAllJokes(data);
```

the way that line was wrote is as if the `makeTableAllJokes` function returns a function that takes data as argument, but that is not the case as it take the argument directly and not through a returned function.

Comment: It works now as intended! kmgt's solution worked. I had somehow missed the extra ()

Comment: if it is a group project i'd recommend setting up some style guides for your code and do peer reviewing to your code after each task is finished. this was a lot of those issue would be avoided.

Comment: also confirm the answer of either me or the other answer so people know the question has been answered